# Sorting array by id

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort make 5 customer objects and sort them with customer ID order while still maintaining name and total owed by the customer. I'm not sure exactly how to sort using ID number while still maintaining the customer name and total associated with the ID. Should I make a `string[] arrayOfString {}`? I have sets and gets in place and the customers made.

```
public class Customer
{

    //Attributes
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private int idNumber;
    private double total;

    //Methods

    public Customer() { }
    public Customer(string aFirstName, string aLastName, int aIDNumber, double aTotal)
    {
        this.SetFirstName(aFirstName);
        this.SetLastName(aLastName);
        this.SetIDNumber(aIDNumber);
        this.SetTotal(aTotal);
        Console.WriteLine(this.Display());

    }


    //Set
    public void SetFirstName(string aFirstName)
    {
        this.firstName = aFirstName;
    }

    public void SetLastName(string aLastName)
    {
        this.lastName = aLastName;
    }

    public void SetIDNumber(int aIDNumber)
    {
        this.idNumber = aIDNumber;
    }

    public void SetTotal(double aTotal)
    {
        this.total = aTotal;
    }

    //Get
    public string GetFirstName()
    {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public string GetLastName()
    {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public int GetIDNumber()
    {
        return this.idNumber;
    }

    public double GetTotal()
    {
        return this.total;
    }

    public string Display()
    {
        return string.Format("Customer Created\r\n" +
        "\tName: {0} {1}\r\n" +
        "\tID: {2}\r\n" +
        "\tBalence: {3}\r\n", this.GetFirstName(), this.GetLastName(), this.GetIDNumber(), this.GetTotal());
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: why don't you put your code in the question?

Comment: Why make us guess what your code looks like? We might guess wrong and give you the wrong answer. That would waste our time and make us think less of you.

Comment: And you don't really want us to think less of you.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<Customer> sortedCustomers = customers.OrderBy(c => c.GetIDNumber()).ToList();
```

I'm also curious to why you don't implement you class like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int IDNumber { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }

    public Customer() { }
    public Customer(string aFirstName, string aLastName, int aIDNumber, double aTotal)
    {
        this.FirstName = aFirstName;
        this.LastName = aLastName;
        this.IDNumber = aIDNumber;
        this.Total = aTotal;
        Console.WriteLine(this.Display());
    }

    public string Display()
    {
        return String.Format(
            "Customer Created\r\n\tName: {0} {1}\r\n\tID: {2}\r\n\tBalance: {3}\r\n",
            this.FirstName, this.LastName, this.IDNumber, this.Total);
    }
}
```

Comment: That set up is much better and cleaner. It's just how I learned I suppose. Thank you

Comment: @JOGO yeah, C# can auto-implement properties set you don't have to write all the getters and setters like in Java.  And the top line uses [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) which is great for manipulating collections.

Answer (score -2):

In order to sort a list of objects (customers in your case) you have to implement the IComparable in your class.

An exmple class:

```
    public class Person : IComparable<Person>, IComparable, ICloneable
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public double Weight { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }

        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract( BirthDate );
                return new DateTime( ts.Ticks ).Year - 1;
            }
        }

        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format( "{0} {1}", LastName, Name ).Trim();
            }
        }



        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format( "[{0}] - {1}, born at {2:dd/MM/yyyy} ({3} years old), {4:#,##0.00} kg", ID, FullName, BirthDate, Age, Weight );
        }

        public override bool Equals( object obj )
        {
            if ( ( obj == null ) || ( !( obj is Person ) ) )
                return false;

            Person other = (Person)obj;

            return ( this.ID == other.ID ) &&
                ( this.Name == other.Name ) &&
                ( this.LastName == other.LastName ) &&
                ( this.BirthDate == other.BirthDate ) &&
                ( this.Weight == other.Weight );

        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return ID.GetHashCode() * 2 +
                Name.GetHashCode() * 3 +
                LastName.GetHashCode() * 4;
        }



        #region IComparable<Person> Members

        public int CompareTo( Person other )
        {
            if ( other == null )
                return -1;

            return this.FullName.CompareTo( other.FullName );
        }

        #endregion

        #region IComparable Members

        public virtual int CompareTo( object obj )
        {
            if ( ( obj == null ) || ( !( obj is Person ) ) )
                return -1;

            Person other = (Person)obj;

            return CompareTo( other );
        }

        #endregion

        #region ICloneable Members

        public virtual object Clone()
        {
            return new Person() { ID = this.ID, Name = this.Name, LastName = this.LastName, BirthDate = this.BirthDate, Weight = this.Weight };
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Please never never never implement `GetHashCode()` that uses values from read/write properties. `.GetHashCode()` **must** remain the same throughout the lifetime of the object if it is used in any data structure that relies on the hash code - like `Dictionary<,>`, `HastSet<>`, `HashTable`.